# Elixir: Multiple instances of a gen_server

Tags: elixir

I have a gen_server module, it does some periodic work: reads from the db, writes to another and sleeps. I want to scale it and start multiple instances of the server. I do it in the following way:

```
def children_spec do
    0..@workers_number - 1
    |> Enum.map(
     fn (i) ->
       process_name = String.to_atom("#{__MODULE__}.#{i}")
       Supervisor.child_spec({__MODULE__, name: process_name}, id: {__MODULE__, i})
     end
    )
end
```

The module has that children_spec function, which returns a list of the child specifications that will be added to the list of the top level application supervisor:

```
children = children ++ MyWorkerModule.children_spec()
Supervisor.init(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
```

Is there another way to do that? Also, I thought about additional supervisor for the module with the :simple_one_for_one strategy

Comment: The way you are doing it looks perfectly fine to me. Supervising children with an intermediate `:simple_one_for_one` supervisor looks like an overkill here, but it might take place in the future: when you’ll _really_ need it, you’ll know that.

Comment: I agree, everything looks fine. However, if your GenServers are only "doing things" without storing any state it may be worth considering changing them to Tasks. They can be dynamically supervised if you wish.

Comment: I want to add `poolboy` too. It is a process pool. There are many examples on web on how to use it, and many libraries use it for worker pools.